# How do I access a custom color that is part of a struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to assign a color to the following button that I gave to a member of a struct previously, yet I keep getting compiler errors. Here's what my code is:

```
var sampleGameView: gameViewState = gameViewState(
Outs: 2, 
Balls: 1, 
Strikes: 1, 
Runner1: true, 
Runner2: true, 
Runner3: false, 
HomeTeam: "MIA", 
AwayTeam: "ATL", 
HomeTeamColor: Color("SampleGameViewATL"), 
AwayTeamColor: Color("SampleGameViewMIA"), 
InningTop: false, 
InningNumber: 4, 
HomeTeamScore: 0, 
AwayTeamScore: 1, 
CurrentBatterFirst: "Starling", 
CurrentBatterLast: "Marte", 
CurrentPitcherFirst: "Max", 
CurrentPitcherLast: "Fried"
)
```

As you can see, `sampleGameView` has two Color properties. However, when I try to assign them to a Button like so, I get errors:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    VStack {
        Text(sampleGameView.CurrentPitcherFirst)
        Text(sampleGameView.CurrentPitcherLast)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .textCase(.uppercase)
    }
    .padding()
}
.foregroundColor(.white)
.frame(width: 170, height: 75)
.background(Color("sampleGameView.HomeTeamColor")) // error is on this line
.cornerRadius(10)
```

I've tried accessing the color without quotes at all, and also with string interpolation, neither of which works :/

Can someone tell me what the correct syntax is for a situation like this? Thank you!

Comment: Give direct : .background(sampleGameView.HomeTeamColor)

Comment: Also, both color property is accessible? I mean is not a private

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it did not work :/ 
Yes, both colors are accessible.

Comment: Please add error

Comment: Never mind, I misread your original comment! I fixed it, and it indeed works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove double quotes and Color object constructor.

```
.background(sampleGameView.HomeTeamColor)
```

Note: Struct and Class name start with capital character and properties start with small character.